# Is token based security in WebAPI2 stateless?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I was just trying to understand the below code:

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

Based upon this line

```
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

It looks like it keeps the claims identity information for every token (until the token expires) somewhere in the cookies on server(sessions). It may be a dictionary with the key as token and value as ClaimsIdentity's object.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the code. *OAuth resolves the token into username and password * - no, the user sends it's credentials(username/password) to the endpoint to request a token and the code above validates the credentials and creates a token.

Comment: yes, right. I misunderstood it.

Comment: @jps I have edited the question now. Could you please help me in understanding it better?

Answer (score 1):

1. based on the username /password and a secret key a token is created
2. This  token is passed with every request.
3. This Token cannnot be altered if it is then the token is declared
   invalid.
4. So no sessionid is reuired the token itself is enough for
   all. Reffer to  https://jwt.io/  .On its home page you could
   visualise the token creation and visualisation of token

Deepak Mishra When you enable Oauth from 3rd party like  Google  it sends most of info  info using query String with callback action/ function  like  this

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=696554540965-tuss1evt7rbudu8rknmh0vb3bvpi8buv.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=zknK7Evpniq6-shKdvjSPQ&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%3A433&approval_state=!ChRpV1JYckwtUTZmaGxNSkk1aVRWXxIfVTdvZEdUU2xsa1VaOEhuU1JuY2dubXItM3JDU0FSYw%E2%88%99AJDr988AAAAAXj0CaAvlDBEoTUtus4huzvphtBXXPAK7&oauthgdpr=1&xsrfsig=ChkAeAh8Tz2ZsIc_iVmqimfC6hrE25szMVwwEg5hcHByb3ZhbF9zdGF0ZRILZGVzdGluYXRpb24SBXNvYWN1Eg9vYXV0aHJpc2t5c2NvcGU&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

the  OAuth library has inbuild capability to decode object

insert into AspNetUsers table with ID and Security Stamp (NOT GOOGLE SID)

and makes entry in cookies in browser and localstaorage for the stateless nature

AND " If by chance I know your encryption algorithm ....."

even if you are able to know encryption algo (which i highly doubt as they have deep in depth mech.) /Their security key  (which again i highly doubt) if you modify it it becomes alterd  or invalid .....

If you create your own library and Allow the invalid token then again you  defy the whole purpose of Oauth

Authentication :The authentication middleware functionality available on the current request.

```
    SignIn:
        Add information to the response environment that will cause the appropriate authentication
             middleware to grant a claims - based identity to the recipient of the response.
             The exact mechanism of this may vary. Examples include setting a cookie, to adding
             a fragment on the redirect url, or producing an OAuth2 access code or token response.

    cookiesIdentity:
        Determines which claims are granted to the signed in user.The ClaimsIdentity.AuthenticationType
             property is compared to the middleware's Options.AuthenticationType value to
             determine which claims are granted by which middleware. The recommended use is
             to have a single ClaimsIdentity which has the AuthenticationType matching a specific
             middleware.
```

Comment: What is this line doing `context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);`